# Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(version) angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

Hello I am facing the problem with schematic error while try to generate new component.

error is as following

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: 
{"version":"6.0.8","styleext":"scss","inlineStyle":false,"inlineTemplate":false,
"changeDetection":"Default","spec":true,"flat":false,"skipImport":false,
"export":false,"entryComponent":false}
Errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(version).
```

I had tried all the possible solution

downgrade the angular version of global to current version of my project 
and also tried by removing node_modules/ folder and reinstall it

I had tried all the options which are given in [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11006) link.

I have also tried `ng g c component-name --version=6.0.8` initially it was working but now it's not working

Answer (score 0):

The link to the github issue you posted states clearly there is an ongoing issue with angular cli and downgrading to 6.0.3 resolves the issue.

Comment: its status is close and there are so many links of github which has same solution but  I have set only one

Answer (score 0):

First remove the node_module then after use the command whichever you want to do.
but it is temporary solution.

Comment: that is the last priority which we can do

Answer (score 0):

you just have to remove the additional properties mentionned in the error like for example:
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(extractCss).
you go to angular.json and remove "extractCss" properties and it will work just fine